# .NET Configuration - how to create an easy to understand configuration

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, configuration

I normally create my classes with some configuration that I inject into them via the constructor. I also use Options Pattern.

For example, I could have a class:

```cs
public class MyService : IMyServce 
{
    private readonly MyServiceOptions _options;
    private readonly ISomeDependency _dependency;

    public MyService(IOptions<MyServiceOptions> options, ISomeDependency dependency)
    {
        _options = options.Value;
        _dependency = dependency;
    }

    //...
}
```

Usually, I create some extension to add it to `IServiceCollection`:

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddMyService(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration, string keyVaultKey, bool isProduction) 
{
    services.AddSignleton<IMyService, MyService>();
    services.AddSignleton<ISomeDependency, SomeDependency>();

    services.Configure<MyServiceOptions>(configuration.GetSection("MyService"));
    services.Configure<SomeDependencyOptions>(configuration.GetSection("SomeDependency"));

    if (isProduction) 
    {
        //use keyVaultKey to load some secrets from Key Vault
    }
}
```

I have a few worries about it:

1. The extension method reads specific sections of the `IConfiguration` object. The user of the code has to go to this specific method to know how to configure his application so that he can use `MyService` correctly. I think it is not really optimal. Another issue with that, I'm using some specific hardcoded name of the section ("MyService"). What if some other service also relies on the same configuration section (I mean, the user could be using two different NuGet packages, where both have extension methods defined where the same confguration section is used). How to handle that?
2. The user is expected to store some secret values in Azure KeyVault.

What are your thoughts about it? My point is to make my services as easy to configure as possible and the process should be as easy to understand as possible.

Comment: i think you may get better answers on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I follow a similar pattern and share your concern.  I don't know that I can make it easy, but I always follow a few rules that tend to make it "easier".

1. Only depend on options that are specific to my service and contained within the namespace of that service.  Outside dependencies should have their own options and its own extension to register that service (including it's own options).
2. Option class should provide defaults where possible and documented to let the user know how to interact with your service (including required settings that come from some `IConfiguration`)
3. I typically use the name of the options class itself using nameof to avoid string literals.
4. Your service extension shouldn't care about how IConfiguration is provided (for example it should not have to know that some settings come from key vault).  I typically make this decision when loading my configuration source in Program and use the environment settings to know what configuration providers to use.

   ```
   public static IServiceCollection AddMyService(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration, string keyVaultKey, bool isProduction)
   {
       services.AddSignleton<IMyService, MyService>();
       services.AddSignleton<ISomeDependency, SomeDependency>();

       services.Configure<MyServiceOptions>(configuration.GetSection(nameof(MyServiceOptions)));
       services.Configure<SomeDependencyOptions>(configuration.GetSection(nameof(SomeDependencyOptions)));
   }

   public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
       Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
           {
               if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
               {
                   // Add your key vault stuff here
               }
           })
           .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
           {
               webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
           });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I think the short answer is: design the service to be easy to configure and provide documentation.

Longer answer

On point 1:

There are two developers in this process. The producer of the service (the person who wrote the MyService), and the consumer of the service (the person who is injecting the service into their application). In this case, the same person, but logically, its two different people.

The producer doesn't care about how the configuration is implemented in the calling application. They only care about making the service easy to use and documenting it (as well as making it work correctly etc).

The consumer should be provided with documentation to ensure they understand how to use the service. They shouldn't be expected to look at the source code of the service to figure out how to make it work.

It is up to the consumer how they store this configuration. They are free to choose what they call their configuration sections. If they want two services using the same configuration section, no problem

```
services.Configure<MyService1Options>(configuration.GetSection("MyService"));
services.Configure<MyService2Options>(configuration.GetSection("MyService"));
```

If they want two services using different configuration sections, again, its up to them

```
services.Configure<MyService1Options>(configuration.GetSection("MyService1"));
services.Configure<MyService2Options>(configuration.GetSection("MyService2"));
```

On point 2:

Using Azure Key Vault is an implementation decision by the consumer. They don't need to use it.